# Can't get shared folders to work in Homestead

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I've been trying to get the shared folder in Homestead but I just can't seem to get it in the Code directory.
Here is the homestead.yaml file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 1024
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    # - map: ~/Projects
    #   to: /home/vagrant/Code

    -map: "%USERPROFILE%/Projects"
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

    # - map: C:/Users/basse/Projects
    #   to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: laravel.doc
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel-basics/public

    - map: dev.furbook.local
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/furbook.com/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

I've tried paths all the different path type I can think of, but still doesn't work.

I can get the shared folder by adding `config.vm.synced_folder "~/Projects", "/home/vagrant/Code"`in the vagrant file in Homestead directory. But the problem is that I don't think any of the mapping defined in the `homestead.yaml` file works. I know this as I cannot see any dir listing in the `home/vagrant/Code directory`.

Before, I got an error like this:

`$ vagrant up
[default] Importing base box 'ubuntu-12.04-64bit'...
[default] The guest additions on this VM do not match the install version of
VirtualBox! This may cause things such as forwarded ports, shared
folders, and more to not work properly. If any of those things fail on
this machine, please update the guest additions and repackage the
box.`

and followed the instruction listed in [Sync Virtual Box Addition](http://kvz.io/blog/2013/01/16/vagrant-tip-keep-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-sync/) but still cannot get it to work.

Comment: P.S: running Windows 10, vagrant ver: 1.8.5, virtualbox ver: 5.1.2, homestead box: v0.5.0